# Stock values after comma from a file in C++

Tags: c++, string, getline

I'm trying to detect and ignore comma from the same line to stock values.

I tried the 3 parameter of getline but it didn't work.
I also tried the iterator, same.

My text file contains the following values:

```
Bob Jackson,25,Sick
Eric Smith,99,Deceased
Alice Vanderlend,16,Healthy
```

In the code below, I put in comment my fail attempts...

```
string str,fn, ln, age, sta;
    ifstream input("text.txt");


    while (getline(input, str)) 
    {   
        /*for ( string::iterator it=str.begin(); it!=str.end(); ++it)
        {
            if ((*it) == ','){continue;};
        }*/

        //string vir;
        istringstream iss(str);

        //if(!(getline(input, vir, ','))){break;}

        iss >> fn >> ln >> age >> sta;

        cout 
        << "First Name: " << fn 
        << "\nLast Name: " << ln 
        << "\nAge: " << age 
        << "\nStatus: " << sta << endl  << endl;

    }
```

The output im expected to get is

```
First Name: Bob
Last Name: Jackson
Age: 25
Status: Sick
...
```

Instead, I get:

```
First Name: Bob
Last Name: Jackson,25,Sick
Age:
Status:
...
```

How to ignore the comma to stock the next value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace all commas in the string with spaces before sending it to the `std::stringstream`:

```
std::replace(str.begin(), str.end(), ',', ' ');
```

Comment: I got error saying : " error: ‘replace’ is not a member of ‘std’
   std::replace(str.begin(), str.end(), ',', ' ');"

Did I miss something? (need to declare a library?)

Comment: @LordRixuel You need to `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: +1 easier for a beginner than what I posted, though learning how to do things like that's worthwhile long term...

Answer (score 2):

Declare a dummy variable as below:

```
char comma;
```

And read out the extra commas:

```
iss >> fn >> ln >> comma>> age >> comma >> sta;
```

instead of

```
iss >> fn >> ln >> age >> sta;
```

Comment: The problem is that "Jackson,25,Sick" will be parsed into ln??? too late to get a comma....

Comment: It might be a good temporary solution somehow, but not all the line is going to be same. Some is going to have no comma, some with comma and a space.

Comment: @LordRixuel jeez - should put details like that in the question!

Comment: Then, use strtok to tokenize

Answer (score 0):

Just change age to an int anyway... assuming that's more convenient for you later, and it's parsing will stop at the comma, but you have to handle the last name string explicitly...

```
char c;
if (iss >> fn && std::getline(iss, ln, ',') && iss >> age >> c >> sta && c == ',')
     ...parsed ok - use vars...
else
    throw std::runtime_error("invalid input");
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the reading code with this

```
iss>>fn;
getline( iss,ln, ',');
getline( iss,age, ',');
getline(iss,sta, ',');
```

The 3rd param to getline is the delimiter.